# insert based on value in first row

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a fixed file that I am importing into a single column with data similar to what you see below:

```
ABC$        WC        11683                                    
11608000163118430001002010056788000000007680031722800315723      
11683000486080280000002010043213000000007120012669100126691      
ABC$        WC                         000000020000000148000     
ABC$        WC        11683                                    
1168101057561604000050200001234000000027020023194001231940      
54322010240519720000502000011682000000035640006721001067210      
1167701030336257000050200008765000000023610029066101151149      
11680010471244820000502000011680000000027515026398201263982
```

I want to split and insert this data into another table but I want to do so as long as the '11683' is equal to a column value in a different table + 1. I will then increment that value (not seen here).

I tried the following:

```
declare @blob as varchar(5) 
declare @Num as varchar(5)

set @blob = substring(sdg_winn_blob.blob, 23,5)
set @Num = (Cnum.num + 1)

IF @blob = @Num
INSERT INTO SDG_CWF
    (
        GAME,SERIAL,WINNER,TYPE
    )
SELECT convert(numeric, substring(blob,28, 5)),convert(numeric, substring(blob, 8, 9)),
        (Case when (substring(blob, 6,2)='10') then '3' 
              when (substring(blob, 6,2)='11') then '4' 
              else substring(blob, 7, 1)
         End),
        (Case when (substring(blob, 52,2)='10') then '3' 
              when (substring(blob, 52,2)='11') then '4' 
              else substring(blob, 53, 1)
         End)

FROM sdg_winn_blob
WHERE blob not like 'ABC$%'
else
print 'The Job Failed'
```

The insert works fine until I try to check to see if the number at position (23, 5) is the same as the number in the Cnum table. I get the error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "sdg_winn_blob.blob" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "Cnum.num" could not be bound.
```

Comment: Have you tried including the schema dbo.Cnum.num & dbo.sdg_winn_blob.blob

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be used to a procedural, object oriented style of coding. SQL Server wants you to think quite differently...

This line:

```
set @blob = substring(sdg_winn_blob.blob, 23,5)
```

Is failing because SQL interprets it in isolation. Within just that line, you haven't told SQL what the object `sdg_winn_blob` is, nor its member `blob`.

Since those things are database tables / columns, they can only be accessed as part of a query including a FROM clause. It's the FROM that tells SQL where these things are.

So you'll need to replace that line (and the immediate next one) with something like the following:

```
Select @blob = substring(sdg_winn_blob.blob, 23,5)
From sdg_winn_blob
Where...
```

Furthermore, as far as I can tell, your whole approach here is conceptually iterative: you're thinking about this in terms of looking at each line in turn, processing it, then moving onto the next. SQL does provide facilities to do that (which you've not used here), but they are very rarely the best solution. SQL prefers (and is optimised for) a *set based* approach: design a query that will operate on all rows in one go.

As it stands I don't think your query will ever do quite what you want, because you're expecting iterative behaviour that SQL doesn't follow.

The way you need to approach this if you want to "think like SQL Server" is to construct (using just SELECT type queries) a set of rows that has the '11683' type values from the header rows, applied to each corresponding "data" row that you want to insert to `SDG_CWF`.

Then you can use a SQL `JOIN` to link this row set to your `Cnum` table and ascertain, for each row, whether it meets the condition you want in `Cnum`.  This set of rows can then just be inserted into `SDG_CWF`.  No variables or IF statement involved (they're necessary in SQL far less often than some people think).

There are multiple possible approaches to this, none of them terribly easy (unless I'm missing something obvious). All will need you to break your logic down into steps, taking your initial set of data (just a blob column) and turning it into something a bit closer to what you need, then repeating. You might want to work this out yourself but if not, I've set out an example in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3058/2).

I don't claim that example is the fastest or neatest (it isn't) but hopefully it'll show what I mean about thinking the way SQL wants you to think. The SQL engine behind that website is using SQL 2008, but the solution I give should work equally well on 2005. There are niftier possible ways if you get access to 2012 or later versions.